# QT with Visual Studio 2013 Express

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to get QT to work with Visual Studio Express 2013.

As first I downloaded sources, and was trying to compile it using Developer Command Prompt for VS2013. Gave up, after adding to QT source files new things, to keep compiler move on.

After that I just installed QT binaries. The QT: "qt-windows-opensource-5.1.1-msvc2012-x86_64-offline.exe"

It has it's own editor, but I would like to use QT inside Visual Studio Express 2013. Can I just link libraries, from Visual Studio Express 2013 project?

I linked C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\include to the Include, C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\lib to the libraries and C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\bin.

But there are a lot os subdirectories, that Visual doesn't include.

Should I wait for QT Sources compatible with Visual Studio Express 2013? 
Or can I use it now, like that?

Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this from cmd.exe you have to edit your `PATH` by adding `QtDir/bin` there, then cd to your project directory and write the line written before.

Everything should looks like this:

1. Run `cmd.exe`
2. `cd your_project_dir/`
3. `qmake -spec win23-msvc2010 -tp vc`

After this manipulations you will have `.vcproject` file in your project directory